# How to execute Build Task only after PR has been reviewed and approved?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pull-request

I may have some expensive tasks/tests and a PR that has not been reviewed could require additional changes.

I don't want to run those expensive tasks for every commit or minor change but only after such changes have been reviewed and approved.

These tasks might not only be expensive to run, but they might also have some run quotas. Moving to a CI build is not desirable given it means that code that breaks the app could get into master and it would require an additional PR to fix.

Is it currently possible in Azure DevOps? How?

Comment: Hi mdarefull, Does my answer help? Please check it and kindly let us know the result. Thanks.

Comment: The answer looks good and it makes total sense... I haven't been able to validate it though, we are prioritizing other tasks. Thank you so much for the quick response, I will validate and notify you ASAP

Comment: Hi mdarefull, How about this issue? Does my answer help? I am lookin forward to hearing from you. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you call this Rest API: [Pull Requests - Get Pull Request By Id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/get%20pull%20request%20by%20id?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1), the response body will return `reviewers` array which contains reviewers information. If there is one reviewer approve(or approve with suggestions) this pull request, the value  of `vote` for this reviewer is positive integer, otherwise it is negative integer. Thus this `vote` property can be used as the flag to check if this pull request is approved or rejected by required reviewers.

Therefore, you could use [PR triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#pr-triggers) instead of [CI triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#ci-triggers), and add a [PowerShell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops) before running those expensive tasks by [specifying conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic). And the [PowerShell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops) will run script using above Rest API to check if this pull request is approved and return the result to be the value of flag variable(`isApproved`), so the flag variable can be passed in those expensive tasks when specifying custom conditions like
`and(succeeded(), eq(variables['isApproved'], 'true'))`.

Comment: This does not work for all cases. Imagine that someone creates a PR and it needs no modifications. Hence, all reviewers would just approve the pull request and the script would not be called!

Comment: @miniplanck the script would be called as part of a pipeline run from a PR trigger; so the PR cannot be completed without running the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [branch policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies-overview?view=azure-devops) and [build pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/what-is-azure-pipelines?view=azure-devops), I do not see a way for Azure DevOps to natively provide an option under "`Policy requirements`" to execute build tasks only after the PR has been approved. The available settings (like [Build validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#build-validation)) relate to whether the build must pass for the PR to be completed, but they do not conditionally trigger the build based on PR approval status.

Given these constraints, you may consider as a possible workaround to use [Azure DevOps REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2) with [scheduled triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#scheduled-triggers)

Set up a scheduled trigger in your build pipeline to run at regular intervals (e.g., every 30 minutes).
At the beginning of the pipeline, use a PowerShell or bash script that leverages the Azure DevOps REST API to check the status of the PRs. Based on the API response, decide whether or not to continue with the execution of the expensive tasks in the pipeline.

A PowerShell snippet could be used to check the status of the PR, but that would require your PAT (Personal Access Token). Since it is not advisable to hard-code sensitive information like a Personal Access Token (PAT) directly in the script, Azure DevOps offers a secure way to handle such secrets by allowing you to define [secret variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-secret-variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbash) in the pipeline. These secret variables are encrypted and can only be decrypted by the pipeline during runtime.

Add first a new "Secret variable" and enter the name for the variable, for example, `PersonalAccessToken`, and its value. Then inject it in the script execution from your pipeline:

```yaml
trigger: none  # Disables the automatic CI trigger

schedules:
- cron: "*/30 * * * *"
  displayName: Run every 30 minutes
  branches:
    include:
    - main  # Replace with the branch you want to monitor

jobs:
- job: CheckPRStatus
  pool:
    vmImage: 'windows-latest'
  steps:
  - script: |
      echo "Running PowerShell script..."
      pwsh -Command "
        \$token = '$(PersonalAccessToken)';
        \$headers = @{
            Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(\":\$token\"))
        }
        \$uri = 'https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pullrequests?api-version=6.0'
        \$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri \$uri -Headers \$headers -Method Get
        foreach (\$pr in \$response.value) {
            if (\$pr.reviewers.status -eq 'approved') {
                Write-Host 'PR with ID ' + \$pr.pullRequestId + ' is approved. Proceed with expensive tasks.'
                # Insert logic to trigger expensive tasks or the next job in the pipeline
            }
        }
      "
    env:
      PersonalAccessToken: $(PersonalAccessToken)
```

Do replace the placeholders `{organization}`, `{project}`, and `{repositoryId}` with your specific Azure DevOps organization, project, and repository ID.

That way, the scheduled pipeline will run at set intervals, but the expensive tasks will only execute if the script confirms that the PR has been approved. That will cover the case where a PR is immediately approved without any modifications.

Answer (score 0):

The general approach to running tasks *after* a PR Approval is to automate those tasks on the target branch, not the source one. The end result of your PR approval is to commit the merge so this makes a lot of sense.

If you are worried about affecting the master branch then you should use an interim/approval/staging/testing branch before going to master, this branch would have the pipeline trigger.

- This has an additional benefit to reducing costs by allowing you to consolidate multiple PRs that have been approved for testing
- This is a basic concept of GitFlow (Feature) branch style

It sounds like you want some of the features from *GitFlow* but you are using *Trunk-based* branching.